# wxPython ListBox event not firing

Tags: events, listbox, wxpython

I have a wx.Dialog that contains a button and 2 ListBoxes, the button `findAppBtn` searches through a list of directories and then displays the result in `actListBox`. Selecting the directory of your choice from `actListBox` should then fire the event `EVT_LISTBOX` which calls `actListBoxList`. This function does an `ls` on the directory and should list the files it finds in the lower list box `binListBox` using Append. Upon selecting an item from the lower ListBox, the window closes.

The problem is that the `self.Bind(EVT_LISTBOX, self.actListBoxList)`  does not seem to be firing when an item is selected.

(also please excuse the bad coding, I am trying to get it working before minifying)

```
    self.findAppBtn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Find app")
    self.findAppBtn.SetDefault()
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.startConf, self.findAppBtn)
    hBox2.Add(self.findAppBtn, 0, flag=wx.LEFT, border=5)
    vBox.Add(hBox2, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=3)

    self.actListBox = wx.ListBox(panel, choices=[])
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.actListBoxList)
    vBox.Add(self.actListBox, 2, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=3)

    self.binListBox = wx.ListBox(panel, choices=[])
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.binListBoxList)
    vBox.Add(self.binListBox, 2, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=3)

    self.closeBtn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_OK)
    hBox4.Add(self.closeBtn, 0, flag=wx.LEFT, border=5)

    vBox.Add(hBox4, 0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM, border=5)

    panel.SetSizer(vBox)


def startConf(self,e):
    val = self.cmdTxt.GetValue().replace(" ","\ ")
    path = "/private/"
    aCmd = "find " + path + " -iname '*"+val+"*.app'"
    try:
        s = pxssh.pxssh()
        s.login(sshIP, "root", sshPort, sshPass)
        s.sendline(aCmd)
        s.prompt()
        AP = s.before
        for m in AP.split('\n'):
            if path in m:
                self.actListBox.Append(m.replace(path,"").strip())
        s.logout()
        return path
    except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
        self.parent.progressBox.AppendText(str(e))


def actListBoxList(self,e):
    #get string from top box selection e.g xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-/myapp.app
    selName = self.actListBox.GetStringSelection() 
    path = "/private/"
    #list all the files in the dir from top box selection
    aCmd = "ls " + path + selName
    try:
        s = pxssh.pxssh()
        s.login(sshIP, "root", sshPort, sshPass)
        s.sendline(aCmd)
        s.prompt()
        ls = s.before
        for file in ls.split('\n'):
            if not file.endswith("/"):
                reg = r"\..*"
                matchObj = re.search(reg, file)
                if not matchObj:
                    self.binListBox.Append(file)
        s.logout()
    except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
        self.parent.progressBox.AppendText(str(e))

def binListBoxList(self,e):
    binaryName = self.binListBox.GetStringSelection()
    self.Close()
```

EDIT: `self.actListBox.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.actListBoxList)` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calling self.Bind(... binds the event to the parent window which is why you're not seeing the event being called. Bind to the listbox instead:

```
self.actListBox.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.actListBoxList)
```